# Google fit through free fall detection

Tags: android, google-fit

I am new in google fit API, I want to know there is any API in google fit that can be through we detect free fall without device motion, like shaking, rotating, and moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right now google fit not support like free-fall detection like apple health kit, you need to go with sensors

I am sharing my approach and findings for this challenge.

step 1) what is free fall and how to solve using algo
https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0037062
https://patents.google.com/patent/US8217795B2/en

step 2)health kit vs google fit
health kit has the option for free-fall detection
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquantitytypeidentifier/1615592-numberoftimesfallen 
google fit:
https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types 
For google fit there no datatype for free fall and as per the below article and spending some hand-on programming I am not finding a way for fall detection
https://www.trustedreviews.com/opinion/what-is-google-fit-2923688

the line
 "Before you even look at third party app compatibility, Apple Health already has more data categories than Google Fit, including blood type, sleep pattern, and how many times you’ve fallen over – if you’re prone to falls."